# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, sequential

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/lambda_layer.py in_serialize_function_to_config(self, inputs, allow_raw)

```
    306             module = inputs.__module__
    307         elif callable(inputs):
--> 308             output = inputs.__name__
    309             output_type = "function"
    310             module = inputs.__module__
```

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '**name**'

This is the error message I am looking at.
I am doing transfer learning for a CNN (Xception) with some layers added before and after.
Yesterday it trained without any issue, now the error above.
I am training on google colab.
I am using loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy().
For the 'lambda_layer' I used tf.keras.layers.Lambda(...).

Every idea is very welcome!

I used the 'Sequential' method at two places in my code, for both I already tried keras.models.Sequential(...) and tf.keras.Sequential(...), and ultmately pip installing tensorflow and keras again.

Comment: Instead of `inputs.__name__`, try `inputs.name`. Docs; https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#args_1

Comment: Always include a reproducible example, with just the error message we cannot really say anything. Code matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are mistakenly using 'Sequential' instead of 'Sequential()' in any part of your code. Ensure that you have instantiated the Sequential model correctly.

Verify that the Lambda layer is defined correctly with the appropriate input and output. Make sure the Lambda layer is being used as intended.

or
Sometimes it may cause the error for versions, once try to check which version does it support. reply to me if you get another error or same error again.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from the following change of mine:

```
model_save = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('./Xception_model.h5',
                             save_best_only = True, 
                             save_weights_only = True,
                             monitor = 'val_loss',
                             mode = 'min', verbose = 1)
```

If in this callback save_weights_only is left out or changed to False, then the '**name**' error occurs.
This should not be the case at least according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/).

Comment: This is why including reproducible code is key, this solution is useless to other people as you did not include this part in the question.

Comment: I get your point, how would you recommend including roughly 150 lines of code in here?